# Transfer resultset of python cx_Oracle to SQL Server table?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, cx-oracle, pypyodbc

I am new to Python and I have asked to transfer the data from the Oracle table to SQL Server table using the python script. I have used cx_Oracle and fetched the data from Oracle this data is like tuple row and I have converted it as a list and then a dictionary. But it doesn't look like table rows. Now how can I import this cx_Oracle resultset to the SQL Server table?

Comment: Your best bet is to get the Oracle data into a Pandas dataframe first.

Comment: If you're new to Python, then start with the latest version of cx_Oracle - it just got renamed to python-oracledb, see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).  I can't comment on the insert: I don't know what format you need. 
 From the fetch side, look at the fetch tuning guide https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance or the cx_Oracle equivalent: https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance